# How to make a field required to enter a specific number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know how can I make a field required to enter a specific number or text [like: Activation code]
and a button to move to a 'Web page' in the case of confirmatory answer of the input and move to 'another page' in the case of non-confirmatory.

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=html%20javascript%20required%20form%20field&safe=active

Comment: Let google "what is javascript?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/XjTL9/)**</kbd>

```
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter activation code">
<input type="button" class="button" value="Confirm">
```

---

```
$(function() {
  var code = '2528-3265-7592';
  $('.button').click(function() {
    if($('.input').val() === code) {
       window.location = 'http://google.com';
    }
    else {
       window.location = 'http://yahoo.com';
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use required attribute:

```
<input type="text" required />
```

Answer (score 1):

To move to a separate page, you may use the header function as such:

```
header("Location:url");
```

To make a field required to take a specific text or number. You may use:

```
<input type="text" required /> //for text
<input type="number" required /> //for number
```

**EDIT**
You may also use the following to move to separate page if you're using only javascript.

```
 window.location="url";
```