# 2-How to make a field required to enter a specific number?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've asked this question in the past ---> 
 [How to make a field required to enter a specific number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859072/how-to-make-a-field-required-to-enter-a-specific-number)

and Mr mdesdev's answer was so helpful to me, his answer source is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/XjTL9/

My problem with this code is that when I press confirm button, it doesn't go to to the specified URL as in the code here:

```
{window.location =
```

So how can I fix this?

Comment: ":>"...  +1 despite your negatives

Comment: Did someone favorite this? Lol!

Comment: @Xero, I think they missed the down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

mdesdev's code is perfectly fine.

You just do not see the HTML of the target page (Google or Yahoo) in JSFiddle. However, if you look at the network traffic in a developer tool of your choice (e.g. Firebug), you will see that the URL is indeed called.